# Stateful EJB not being passivated when the client VM is abruptly terminated

Tags: java, jboss, ejb

I have an stateful session bean deployed on Jboss 4.3 with the following config on jboss.xml:

```
<cache-config>
      <idle-timeout-seconds>7200</idle-timeout-seconds>
      <remove-timeout-seconds>8000</remove-timeout-seconds>
</cache-config>
```

IE:

The bean should be passivated after 2 hours of IDLE and removed after 2 hours and 15 minutes.

The problem is: when the client VM is abruptly terminated the bean is neither passivated nor removed.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

> A container may only passivate a stateful session bean instance when
> the instance is not in a transaction.
>
> A container must not passivate a stateful session bean with an
> extended persistence context unless the following conditions are met:
>
> - All the entities in the persistence context are serializable.
> - The EntityManager is serializable.
>
> Any interceptor classes associated with the stateful session bean must be Serializable.

The references *can possibly* restrict the bean from getting passivated.

Comment: I'm not using Bean Transaction management and I'm also not using persistence. There are no interceptors either.

Comment: It can be in a transaction, whether handled by bean or by container. Also the operations performed in the bean or any other references may be preventing it from being passivated.